# pcolor plotting a flipped array

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

This is my numpy array

```
    array = np.array(([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
    0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.,
    1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
    0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1.,
    1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
    1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
    0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1.,
    1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1.,
    0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,
    1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
    0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
    1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.,
    0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]))
```

When I plot it using pcolor

```
plt.pcolor(array, cmap = "Greys", edgecolors = "Grey", linewidths = 1)
```

The output is actually the mirrored version of the array

For example, the first black square in the first row of the  image should actually be in the place of the last black square in the last row of the image etc...

How do I stop it from being mirrored?

Alternatively for a simple example:

```
array = np.eye(5)
plt.pcolor(array)
```

The output will be mirrored

Comment: `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()` or `plt.gca().invert_xaxis()` depending on which axis you want to invert. Alternatively, just call `pcolor` with `plt.pcolor(array[:,::-1], ...)`.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work. Do you know why it does that? Is it just the default behaviour of pcolor?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html has some context about why the axis is / is not inverted.  In sort, there are multiple "obviously correct" behavior that are different ;)